# Unable to customize git commit-msg hook

Tags: git, ubuntu

I am trying to customize git commit-msg hook to check for a particular format of string before committing the code.

But for some reason it is not working, it gives the following error:

```
.git/hooks/commit-msg: 26: .git/hooks/commit-msg: message_file: not found
.git/hooks/commit-msg: 27: .git/hooks/commit-msg: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Code written in .git/hooks/commit-msg :

```
#!/bin/sh
message_file = ARGV[0]
message = File.read(message_file)

$regex = /^TEST/

if !$regex.match(message)
  puts "[POLICY] Your message is not formatted correctly"
  exit 1
end
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: In shell scripting, variable assignments look like this - `variable=value` - not like this - `variable = value`. See the difference? It also appears as if you want your Posix shell to somehow magically run Perl code...

Comment: I am not trying anything new, I am just trying to follow the git documentation(http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy)

Comment: Then perhaps you need to notice the part where the first line of those scripts reads `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` instead of `#!/bin/sh`... What I mistakenly saw as Perl before now appears to be Ruby instead, but the Bourne/Posix shell still won't know what to do with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the fix.
I was using:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Replaced it with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

And it worked like a charm.